# Positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=n$ , prove: $\displaystyle\sum_{sym}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^i}}\leqslant n!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ satisfy $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=n$ , prove or falsify:

> $$\sum_{\text{sym}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^i}}\leqslant n!$$

Here I'll explain the notation 'sym',

$$
\sum_\text{sym}{f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}{f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})}}
$$

where $S_n$ is the permutation group of degree $n$ .

For example,

$$
\sum_{\text{sym}}{x^3y^2z}=x^3y^2z+x^3yz^2+x^2y^3z+x^2yz^3+xy^3z^2+xy^2z^3
$$

The above example corresponds to the LHS of the case $n=3$ of this problem.

I haven't push forward this question much, all I can prove is the case $n=2$ , which is immediately true by AM-GM. For $n=3$ , I tried to homogenise the inequality and use the 'SOS' method(Sum Of Squares), but it's apparent that this attempt can't be generalised.

I've managed to solved the $n=3$ case by the $pqr$ method. First, note the identity

$$
\sum_{\text{sym}}{a^3b^2c}=abc(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-3(abc)^2
$$

Let $p:=a+b+c,~q:=ab+bc+ca,~r:=abc$ , the inequality is equivalent to

$$
pqr-3r^2\leqslant 6
$$

By Schur's Inequality of degree 3, we have

$$
a(a-b)(a-c)+b(b-a)(b-c)+c(c-a)(c-b)=p^3-4pq+9r\geqslant0
$$

From this we may obtain $q\leqslant(p^3+9r)/(4p)$ , and as constrained we have $p=3$ ,these reduce the inequality to

$$
3r^2-3r~\left(\frac{27+9r}{12}\right)+6=3(r-1)(r-8)\geqslant0
$$

By AM-GM, we obtain $r\leqslant(p/3)^3=1$ ,which proves the inequality.

Here's a [proof](https://www.zhihu.com/question/544118158/answer/2584100860) on the site 'zhihu', I've reposted it as community wiki. This proof is invalid because its lemma is wrong.

Thanks to Sangchul Lee, this inequality is not true for $n\geqslant6$ , which means the cases $n=4$ and $n=5$ might be very difficult to prove.

Comment: When each $x_i=1,$ you get equality. So the upper bound, if true, is "tight." Try some small $n,$ like $2$ and $3.$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please explain what you have made before. What means the sym sum here because all the indexes are put in the product indexations ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality

Comment: @ErikSatie I've tried Muirhead, but it didn't work out. Would you share your idea on the way of using it?

Comment: Neither Muirhead, nor induction will be straightforward if at all possible. For $n=3:$


$$F\left(\frac{x+y}{2}, \frac{x+y}{2},z\right) - F(x,y,z) =xyz\left(\frac 14(x+y)(x-y)^2 -\frac 12 z(x-y)^2\right)  = \frac 14xyz(x-y)^2(x+y-2z)\geq 0$$
if $z =\min\{x,y,z\}$ is less than at least one of them i.e., not all equal. You might be able to do something like this but I think it will get ugly.

Comment: Has this been posted on Art of Problem Solving? If this is Olympiad-style, you might get an answer faster on that website

Comment: I just don't know if this inequality is too difficult for Olympiad contests

Comment: @O-17 There is simpler in the case you describe in example there is always a permutation such that $a^ib^jc^k+a^{i\pm k}b^{j\pm m}c^{k\pm n}\leq 2$ if you show it I think there is the general case too .

Comment: For $n=4$ it's true for non-negative variables.

Answer (score 9):

A simulation suggests that the inequality is true for $n \leq 5$.

However, the inequality is **not true** for $n \geq 6$. For example, let $n = 6$, introduce the parameter $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$, and define $(x_1, \ldots, x_6)$ by

$$ x_1 = 1 - 2\varepsilon, \qquad x_2 = x_3 = 1 + \varepsilon, \qquad x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = 1. $$

Clearly $\sum_{i=1}^{6} x_i = 6$. However,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma \in S_6} \prod_{i=1}^{6} x_{\sigma(i)}^i
&= \sum_{\sigma \in S_6} \prod_{i=1}^{6} x_i^{\sigma(i)} \\
&= \sum_{\sigma \in S_6} (1 - 2\varepsilon)^{\sigma(1)}(1 + \varepsilon)^{\sigma(2)+\sigma(3)} \\
&= 720 + 2520 \varepsilon^3 + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^4) \\
&> 6!
\end{align*}

for any sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. In fact, even moderately small values such as $\varepsilon = 0.2$ work. Below is a comparison of the values between the above sum as a function of $\varepsilon$ and $6!$:

[image: Comparison of the values]

For $n \geq 7$, an even simpler choice $x_1 = 1-\varepsilon$, $x_2 = 1+\varepsilon$, $x_3 = \ldots = x_n = 1$ works.

Comment: Now this inequality seems quite curious, the cases $n=4,5$ are likely to be very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

A proof for $n=4$ and non-negative variables.

We need to prove that $$abcd\sum_{sym}a^3b^2c\leq24,$$ where $a+b+c+d=4$.

Indeed, let $a+b+c+d=4u$, $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=6v^2$, $abc+abd+acd+bcd=4w^3$ and $abcd=t^4$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$t^4(96uv^2w^3-48w^6-48u^2t^4+24v^2t^4)\leq24u^{10}$$ or
$$u^{10}-4uv^2w^3t^4+2w^6t^4+2u^2t^8-v^2t^8\geq0.$$

Since $u^2\geq v^2$ and $t^8\geq0$, by AM-GM we obtain:

$$u^{10}-4uv^2w^3t^4+2w^6t^4+2u^2t^8-v^2t^8\geq u^{10}-4uv^2w^3t^4+2w^6t^4+u^2t^8\geq$$
$$\geq4\sqrt[4]{u^{10}\cdot(w^6t^4)^2\cdot u^2t^8}-4uv^2w^3t^4=4uw^3t^4(u^2-v^2)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 0):

This a [proof](https://www.zhihu.com/question/544118158/answer/2584100860) on the site 'zhihu' , and I'll repost it here in English. (All I've done is translation, please inform me if it's illegal.)

**Lemma.** For all integers $p,q\geqslant1$ , let

$$
f(x):=x^p(m-x)^q+x^q(m-x)^p~(0\leqslant x\leqslant m)
$$

Then $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing on the interval $\left[0,m/2\right]$ and monotonically decreasing on the interval $\left[m/2,m\right]$ .

**Proof.** By taking derivatives, we obtain

$$
f^\prime(x)=(p+q)(m-2x)x^{p-1}(m-x)^{q-1}
$$

The sign of $f^\prime(x)$ depends solely on the sign of $(m-2x)$ , which proves the statement. $\square$

**Theorem.** Given positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=n$ , the following inequality holds true.

$$
\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^{\sigma(i)}}\leqslant n!
$$

**Proof.** If $x_i=1$ for all $i$ , the equality occurs. Now for cases where $x_i$ don't all equal to $1$ , we may divide them into three categories depending on whether they are $<1,=1,>1$ .

Select $x_u<1,~x_v>1$ , let $d:=\min\{1-x_u,x_v-1\}$ . Define a transformation as substituting $x_u$ with $x_u+d$ and $x_v$ with $x_v-d$ .

Note that this transformation maintains the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=n$ , and it leads to at least one of $x_u$ and $x_v$ turning into $1$ . By the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=n$ , we can tell that whenever there exists some $x_i<1$ , there must exist some $x_j>1$ . It can be concluded from above that after finitely many times of transformation, we may obtain the case where $x_i=1$ for all $i$ , in which the equality occurs.

Therefore, it suffices to show that $\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^{\sigma(i)}}$ is monotonically increasing after each transformation.

Consider a specific pair of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ such that

$$
\sigma_2(i)=\begin{cases}\sigma_1(v)&i=u\\\sigma_1(u)&i=v\\\sigma_1(i)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Denote $X:=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^{\sigma_1(i)}}+\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^{\sigma_2(i)}}$ and $Y:=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{y_i^{\sigma_1(i)}}+\prod_{i=1}^{n}{y_i^{\sigma_2(i)}}$ , where

$$
y_i=\begin{cases}x_i+d&i=u\\x_i-d&i=v\\x_i&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Firstly, we'll show that $X\leqslant Y$ . By eliminating their common factor, it's equivalent to show that

$$
x_u^{\sigma_1(u)}x_v^{\sigma_1(v)}+x_u^{\sigma_2(u)}x_v^{\sigma_2(v)}
\leqslant
y_u^{\sigma_1(u)}y_v^{\sigma_1(v)}+y_u^{\sigma_2(u)}y_v^{\sigma_2(v)}
$$

Let $m:=x_u+x_v,~p=\sigma_1(u),~q=\sigma(v)$ , the above equality is equivalent to $f(x_u)\leqslant f(y_u)$ , where $f$ is defined in the lemma.

Note that $x_u<1<x_v$ and $y_u\leqslant 1\leqslant y_v$ , thus $x_u,y_u\in\left[0,m/2\right]$ . By the lemma, we obtain $f(x_u)\leqslant f(y_u)$ , which proves the inequality $X\leqslant Y$ .

Note that all of the permutations in $S_n$ can be divided into  $n!/2$ pairs such that the two permutations $\sigma_1,~\sigma_2$ in each pair satisfy

$$
\sigma_2(i)=\begin{cases}\sigma_1(v)&i=u\\\sigma_1(u)&i=v\\\sigma_1(i)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

where $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary intergers between $1$ and $n$ .

Now that finitely many times of transformation ends up with the  occurence of equality, in the process of which the $\text{LHS}$ is monotonically increasing, the theorem is proven. $\square$

Comment: As in my answer, there are counter-examples to the inequality for $n \geq 6$. So the proof must have some flaws. For example, the very first lemma is wrong: If $p=1$ and $q=4$, then the function $f$ in the statement is bimodal, having two local maxima on the interval $[0, m]$. I did not read everything, but this already seems a red flag to me.

Comment: @SangchulLee Right, the author must have made a mistake while factorising the derivatives.

Comment: @O-17 A simple way to see an error was made is to note $f$ is symmetric with respect to $p,q$ but the proposed $f'$ isn't unless $p=q$.

Answer (score -2):

Too long for a comment :

Let $x,y,z,d>0$ such that $x+y+z+d=4$ and define :

$$M_1=\max{(d^4x^3y^2z,d^4x^3yz^2,d^4x^2y^3z,d^4x^2yz^3,d^4xy^3z^2,d^4xy^2z^3)}$$
$$M_2=\max{(z^4x^3y^2d,z^4x^3yd^2,z^4x^2y^3d,z^4x^2yd^3,z^4xy^3d^2,z^4xy^2d^3)}$$
$$M_3=\max{(x^4z^3y^2d,x^4z^3yd^2,x^4z^2y^3d,x^4z^2yd^3,x^4zy^3d^2,x^4zy^2d^3)}$$
$$M_4=\max{(y^4z^3x^2d,y^4z^3xd^2,y^4z^2x^3d,y^4z^2xd^3,y^4zx^3d^2,y^4zx^2d^3)}$$

$$m_1=\min{(d^4x^3y^2z,d^4x^3yz^2,d^4x^2y^3z,d^4x^2yz^3,d^4xy^3z^2,d^4xy^2z^3)}$$
$$m_2=\min{(z^4x^3y^2d,z^4x^3yd^2,z^4x^2y^3d,z^4x^2yd^3,z^4xy^3d^2,z^4xy^2d^3)}$$
$$m_3=\min{(x^4z^3y^2d,x^4z^3yd^2,x^4z^2y^3d,x^4z^2yd^3,x^4zy^3d^2,x^4zy^2d^3)}$$
$$m_4=\min{(y^4z^3x^2d,y^4z^3xd^2,y^4z^2x^3d,y^4z^2xd^3,y^4zx^3d^2,y^4zx^2d^3)}$$

Then it seems we have $x,y\in[0,2],z\in[0,1]$:

$$M_{1}+M_{3}+M_{4}+M_{2}+m_{1}+m_{3}+m_{4}+m_{2}\le8+\max(x,y,z,d)-\min(x,y,z,d)$$

@MartinR :

I split in three case the inequality such that we have a system of inequalities like :

$$I_1\leq a-b+8,I_2\leq b-c+8,I_3\leq c-a+8$$

Where $$I_1+I_2+I_3\leq 4!$$

Corresponding to the case $n=4$

In waiting a proof :

The case $n=3$ :

We need to show  :

$$xyz(x^{2}z+z^{2}x+zy^{2}+yz^{2}+y^{2}x+yx^{2})\leq 6$$

Or :

$$xyz((x+y+z)(xy+zx+zy)-3xyz)\leq 6$$

Or :

$$xyz((x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)/3+3xyz)\leq 2+4x^2y^2z^2$$

Remark that if :

$$a_1=xy,a_2=yz,a_3=zx,a_4=(x+y+z)/3$$

We have :

$$\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}\right)a_{4}+a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}a_{3}+a_{3}a_{1}-\left(x+y+z\right)\left(xy+yz+zx\right)/3-xyz=0$$

Then by Maclaurin's inequality we need to show :

$$xyz\frac{6(1+xy+zy+zx)^2}{16}-4x^2y^2z^2\leq 2$$

Or :

We have the easy inequality :

$$xy+yz+zx<2.25+0.75xyz$$

Remains to show :

$$xyz\frac{6(1+2.25+0.75xyz)^{2}}{16}-4x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}-2\leq 0$$

Wich is a single variable inequality .

Perhaps we can prove the case $n=4$ with the Maclaurin's inequality .

We have a useful lemma for the case $n=4$ :

Let $x,y,z,d>0,x+y+z+d=4,xyz\leq d$ :

$$\left(4-y-z-d\right)y+yz+z\left(4-y-z-d\right)\leq 4-yz\left(4-d-y-z\right)$$

Wich is of use with the expression :

$$d^{4}xyz\left(\left(xy+yz+zx\right)\left(4-d\right)-3xyz\right)$$

---

---

$\exists b,c,d,a>0,a+b+c+d=4$ and $\exists u\in(-\infty,\infty)$ such that :

$$\left(4-c-b-d\right)b+bc+c\left(4-b-c-d\right)-2-\frac{\frac{3}{u}-\frac{1}{u+2}}{\frac{\left(b+c+d\right)}{u}-\frac{bc\left(4-b-c-d\right)}{u+2}}\leq 0$$

Then define :

$$f\left(x\right)=x^{3}dabc\left(\left(2+\frac{\frac{3}{u}-\frac{1}{u+2}}{\frac{\left(4-x\right)}{u}-\frac{dabc}{x\left(u+2\right)}}\right)\left(4-x\right)-\frac{3abcd}{x}\right),g\left(x\right)=x^{3}dabc\left(\left(2+\frac{\frac{3}{v}-\frac{1}{v+2}}{\frac{\left(4-x\right)}{v}-\frac{dabc}{x\left(v+2\right)}}\right)\left(4-x\right)-\frac{3abcd}{x}\right)$$

As the assumption above and $\exists v\in(-\infty,\infty)$ such that :

$$f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)+g\left(d\right)+g\left(c\right)\leq 4!$$

Comment: What are $i, j$ in the last inequality? Why should that inequality be true? And how is it related to the inequality from the question?

Comment: @MartinR see my explanations in the answer .

Comment: It seems we have : $$a^{4}g\left(b,c,d\right)+b^{4}g\left(a,c,d\right)+c^{4}g\left(a,b,d\right)+d^{4}g\left(a,b,c\right)\leq f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)+f\left(c\right)+f\left(d\right)\leq 24$$ where $a,b,c,d>0,a+b+c+d=4,u=-3.4,d\geq b \geq a \ge c$ and $$g\left(x,y,z\right)=xyz\left(\left(xy+yz+zx\right)\left(x+y+z\right)-3xyz\right),f\left(x\right)=x^{3}abcd\left(\left(2+\frac{\frac{3}{u}-\frac{1}{u+2}}{\frac{\left(4-x\right)}{u}-\frac{dabc}{x\left(u+2\right)}}\right)\left(4-x\right)-\frac{3abcd}{x}\right)$$

Comment: It's $d\geq 1\ge b \ge a \ge c$ for the previous comment .

Comment: We have with the assumptions of the two comments : $$a^{4}g\left(b,c,d\right)+b^{4}g\left(a,c,d\right)+c^{4}g\left(a,b,d\right)+d^{4}g\left(a,b,c\right)\leq f(d)+3f(4/3-d/3)\leq f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)+f\left(c\right)+f\left(d\right)\leq f\left(d\right)+f\left(c\right)+f\left(a\right)+h\left(4-a-d-c\right)\leq 24$$ where : $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(f\left(a\right)-f\left(d\right)\right)}{a-d}\left(x-a\right)+f\left(a\right)$$